# Set condition based on inner text of node?

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api, bookmarklet

```
(function() {
  var i=0;
  var f=function() {
    let l=document.querySelector("*[data-control-name=withdraw_single]");
    if (!!l) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        l.click();
      }, 100);
      setTimeout(function() {
        document.querySelector(".artdeco-modal .artdeco-button--primary").click();
      },1500);
      setTimeout(function() {
        f();
      },2500);
    }
  };
  f();
})()
```

The above javascript bookmarklet works well for automating the invitation withdraw process on LinkedIn. However, there is a value in this element that I am hoping to factor in:

```
<time class="time-badge time-ago">
  1 day ago
</time>
```

Any idea on how to add a condition to only move forward with the process ONLY if this 'time-ago' value is greater than [X] days ago, otherwise STOP the process just provide an alert like 'All invites older than [X] days ago withdrawn.'

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, you could try to do this:

```
...
let val = parseInt(document.querySelector(".time-badge").innerText.split(' ')[0]);
if (val > [X]){
   // go forward
}
else {
   // stop
   alert('All invites older than [X] days ago withdrawn.');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "<time class=\"time-badge time-ago\"> 1 day ago </time>";
  var patt = /\> (.*?) day ago \<\/time>/i;
  var result = str.match(patt);
  if(result !== undefined  && result !== null){
      var day = parseInt(result[1]);
      if(day <= 10){  
          // include results upto 10 days 
      } else {
         // exclude results
      }
  }
```